# Error when retrieving OData data when using OData4J

Tags: java, android, odata, odata4j

I am trying to use [OData4J](http://code.google.com/p/odata4j/) to retrieve a list of Users from the StackOverflow OData service (onto an Android 2.1 device), but it isn't working.

```
public static Enumerable<OEntity> getUserInfo() { 


ODataConsumer c = ODataConsumer.create("https://odata.sqlazurelabs.com/OData.svc/v0.1/rp1uiewita/StackOverflow/"); 


return c.getEntities("Users").execute();
```

I think it is unable to retrieve data from the URL.

Any ideas why this would be? Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: Error message?  What's the result?

Comment: Is this the same manifest issue described here?  http://groups.google.com/group/odata4j-discuss/browse_thread/thread/5873ef4fd140bf56

Comment: Yes it is, but I forgot to add the answer here too. Now added :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was because I was missing the security in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

After adding that it now works.